# make: can't find /usr/include/linux/ext3_fs.h

Tags: linux, makefile, kernel, fedora, ext3

When I try to compile one of my old program which uses ext3 structure with new Fedora 16

I get the message

```
# make
Compile main.c In file included from main.c:8:0:
giis.h:18:28: fatal error: linux/ext3_fs.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I did yum install kernel-devel and kernel-headers - but still it gives above message.

```
# uname -a
Linux space 3.2.9-2.fc16.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Mar 5 20:55:39 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linux kernel does not export a header called `ext3_fs.h`, or does not do so anymore. Edit your `giis.h` to do without it. See commit `v2.6.25-rc8~52`: “Neither of the headers actually compiles when included from userpsace nor should it be made available as userspace tools should be using the libraries or at least headers from e2fsprogs.”

Comment: This is not true. Linux kernel has `ext3_fs.h` file in `/usr/src/linux-$(uname-r)/include` or similar directory. I have it in my ubuntu.

Comment: `/usr/src/linux/include` does not include headers not intended nor sanitized for userspace. So of course I am talking about `/usr/include` having no `linux/ext3_fs.h`. I derived that you had a userspace program from the fact that you did not post a complete build log showing a kernel module build.